# Cells not displaying for UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am following a tutorial building a weather app, but for me the cells are not displaying any data.

This is my UITableViewController code

```
class WeatherTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var cellViewModels = [WeatherCellViewModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                do {

                    ...


                } catch {
                        print("weather endpoint error")
                    }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            case .error(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        print("cellViewModels.count")
        print(cellViewModels.count)
        return cellViewModels.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WeatherCell", for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        let cellViewModel = cellViewModels[indexPath.row]

        print("hello")
        print(cellViewModel.description)

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = cellViewModel.description
        return cell
    }
}
```

cellViewModels.count prints out as 40, and cellViewModel.description prints out "hello" and a short description 40 times.

I have set up WeatherCell to be the identifier of my cell in my storyboard.

Comment: Is each description printed along with "hello" the proper description? Try setting `cell.textLabel.text` instead of `detailTextLabel`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot